# How to test and automate APIs implemented in GraphQL

Tags: automated-testing, api-testing

In our company, we are creating APIs using '[GraphQL](https://graphql.org/)'.

I want to test and automate this API for CI/CD. I have tried 'REST assured' but it doesn't have proper support for 'GraphQL' queries yet, please suggest which tools we can use and automate these APIs for CI/CD.

Comment: Can anyone share a full sample example which worked successfully with correct graphql query rest-assured.
It will be helpful

Comment: There is a full sample in my answer. What problem are you facing with that?

Answer (score 4):

You should approach with REST Assured one more time. Actually it should perfectly fit your needs. When you run GraphQL service you basically run a REST end-point where you send some query and receive JSON as a response.

So nothing prevents you from using REST Assured since you can send whatever as a requests and at the same time it provides good tool set for parsing JSON response.

**UPD:**

Below you can find my example for your case  (Rest Assured + TestNg):

```
@Test
public void testGraphQL() throws MalformedURLException {
    String actual = RestAssured.
                                given()
                                    .header(new Header("Content-type", "application/json"))
                                    .body("{\"query\":\"{\\n Country(id: \\\"us\\\") {\\n name\\n situation\\n }\\n}\\n \"}")
                                .post(new URL("https://portal.ehri-project.eu/api/graphql"))
                                .jsonPath().getString("data.Country.name");
    Assert.assertEquals(actual, "United Sttates");
}
```

With the following output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [United Sttates] but found [United States]
Expected :United Sttates
Actual   :United States
 <Click to see difference>
```

**P.S.** - This is the query that you have provided in your comment, however you can omit `\n` with no impact to your test.

Comment: Hi Alexey, Yes REST assured is a perfect tool for the API automation.
Please, can you elaborate more on how we can send a get request with graphQL query in the payload? please also refer to this link
https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/958

Comment: Give me actionable GraphQL endpoint and data model to query and I'll try to help.

Comment: Hi Alexey, sharing a cURL call, I want to use similar kind of request in REST assured automation  
`curl -X POST \
  https://portal.ehri-project.eu/api/graphql \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{"query":"{\n  Country(id: \"us\") {\n    name\n    situation\n  }\n}\n    "}'`

Comment: @swapnil.s check my update

Answer (score 0):

I am using SoapUI 5.4.0 (community edition) for testing GraphQL requests.
Treat them as a Rest request and add a header, e.g. Content-Type: application/graphql

[image: see image for all details]

Comment: The Content-Type: application/graphql is not yet completely supported

https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/

Answer (score 0):

You can try `webtau` framework me and my friends are developing: https://testingisdocumenting.org/webtau/GraphQL/queries-and-mutations

```
def taskByIdQuery = '''
query taskById($id: ID!) {
    taskById(id: $id) {
        id
        description
        completed
    }
}
'''
```

```
graphql.execute(taskByIdQuery, [id: "a"]) {
  errors.should == null
  taskById.id.should == "a"
  taskById.completed.should == true
}
```